# Importing data with numpy.loadtxt: No delimiters but fixed column width

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to import data with python/numpy.loadtxt. With most of the data this isn't a problem, e.g. if a row looks like this:

```
0.000000      0.000000      0.000000      0.000000    -0.1725804E-13
```

In this case I can use white space as the delimiter. Unfortunately the program which produces the data doesn't use delimiters, just a fixed column width (and I can't change that). Example:

```
-0.1240503E-03-0.6231297E-04  0.000000      0.000000    -0.1126164E-02
```

Can I tell numpy.loadtxt in some easy way that every column is 14 characters? I'd prefer to not have to modify the files the other program produces manually...

**EDIT:**

I thought I share my very simple solution based on dxwx's suggestion. For the example I provided the solution would be

```
a = numpy.genfromtxt('/path/to/file.txt', delimiter = 14)
```

There was a additional whitespace before the first column in my real data, and I didn't want to use the last column and the last row. So it looks like this now:

```
a = numpy.genfromtxt('/path/to/file.txt',
                     delimiter = (1,14,14,14,14,14,14), 
                     usecols = range(1,6), skip_footer = 1)
```

Thanks everyone for the fast response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at Numpy's [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) - that says it can use an integer width for the separator.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [numpy.fromregex](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html) instead. You can then just define a basic regular expression to capture up to 14 characters.

So, here we capture each field with the RE group `[-.\dE]{1,14}` (which assumes that there are no missing values and that the format always matches the example you gave, regarding which characters are possible):

```
>>> regex = r"([-.\dE]{1,14})\s*([-.\dE]{1,14})\s*([-.\dE]{1,14})\s*([-.\dE]{1,14})\s*([-.\dE]{1,14})"
>>> np.fromregex(dat, regex, [('A', np.float32), ('B', np.float32),('C', np.float32),('D', np.float32),('E', np.float32),])
array([ (-0.0001240503042936325, -6.231296720216051e-05, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0011261639883741736)
], 
      dtype=[('A', '<f4'), ('B', '<f4'), ('C', '<f4'), ('D', '<f4'), ('E', '<f4')])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has taught me a more general approach for importing data :). dwxw's answer is simpler though and works as well.